# Cannot find document for some gcc options. Is there any more complete gcc options index webpage?

Tags: gcc

I bookmarked a gcc options index webpage where I can search for options I encountered in various Makefiles. [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Option-Index.html) is the link. But recently I noticed that more and more gcc options cannot be found in that webpage, for example, `-fno-pie`, `-fno-strict-aliasing`, `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. If I really missed them by accident, please let me know. If not, are these gcc options deprecated? For example, is `-fno-pie` replaced with `-no-pie`? Is there any more complete gcc options index webpage? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are listed as `fpie`, `fstrict-aliasing`, and `fomit-frame-pointer`; the `no-` prefix just turns the flags off. As the page says at the top:

> Where an option has both positive and negative forms (such as -foption and -fno-option), relevant entries in the manual are indexed under the most appropriate form; it may sometimes be useful to look up both forms.

None of the flags you mention are deprecated.